# web3 stuck at sendTransaction

Tags: web3js

I'm following the tutorial here: https://chainstack.com/how-to-create-blockchain-bridge/ and getting stuck (seeing nothing) at line 34 in [contract-methods.js](https://github.com/chainstack/blockchain-bridge-simplified/blob/master/backend/contract-methods.js) and if I set timeouts, I get a timeout.

Here's the repo for it: https://github.com/chainstack/blockchain-bridge-simplified

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

hey  I'm the author of the article. The first thing that come to mind is: have you deployed the ERC20 token contracts in both chains? In addition, have you set up all the environment variables for the backend job?

```
BRIDGE_WALLET
ORIGIN_TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS
DESTINATION_TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS
```

Feel free to [contact me on our Discord](https://discord.gg/Cymtg2f7pX) and I'll be happy to help ✌️

Comment: Yes to your questions above and okay, I'll come contact you on the discord! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the DogeChain https RPC endpoint prefixed with wss:// and postfixed with /ws but I spoke with someone in the DogeChain team and there's no WSS endpoint yet so that's why the sendTransaction was having an error.